# Fake media is not working on firefox browser version 74

Tags: firefox, screensharing, mediastream

I am testing a website in which i have to validate screen sharing is working properly on two different browser. I am trying to use fake media for the testing. But on firefox I am not able to enable it. I am using below preferences:

```
'media.webrtc.hw.h264.enabled': true,
'media.getusermedia.screensharing.enabled': true,
'media.navigator.permission.disabled': true,
'media.navigator.streams.fake': true,
'media.peerconnection.video.h264_enabled': true
```

because of this I am not able to test it on browserstack.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Using your shared preferences:

```
'media.webrtc.hw.h264.enabled': true,
'media.getusermedia.screensharing.enabled': true,
'media.navigator.permission.disabled': true,
'media.navigator.streams.fake': true,
'media.peerconnection.video.h264_enabled': true
```

I could get a fake media feed on https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/devices/input-output/ using firefox.

See this firefox test:

[image: firefox test]